# Browser extension for reverse image search

Tags: gratis, images, web-browser, search-engine

I am looking for a browser extension for reverse image search via supported search engines.

It should be free for use, ideally for Chrome or Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

#### [`dessant/search-by-image`](https://github.com/dessant/search-by-image)

*Search by Image* extension, MIT-licensed, available on Chrome and Firefox enables you to initiate a reverse image search.

Supported search engines:

- Google Images
- Bing Images
- Yandex.Images
- Baidu Image Search
- TinEye Reverse Image Search
- Sogou Images
- Karma Decay
- WhatAnime
- SauceNAO
- Iqdb
- Ascii2d